# Wordpress - Update ALL menu links in header with querystring value

Tags: wordpress, url, menu, query-string, hyperlink

I am trying to use wordpress to make a website replicate...  So, when the viewer comes to http://www.wpsite.com/1005, I do a check (through an API) to see if the id is a valid/active rep, then set a cookie for the usual stuff (name, email, repid) and redirect to the main page:

http://www.wpsite.com/wp/?page_id=34&id=1005

I have all of this functioning currently.

so at this point, I want to pass the "id=1005" to ALL of the menu links at the top of the page.  My site is using the Appearance -> Menus functionality in wordpress to build the menu...

So when the viewer hovers over/clicks any link on the site, I want the "&id=1005" to be added to it.  Is that possible?  What if the user isn't valid and there is no "&id=1005"?  Thanks.

Adam

Update:  Ok, I create a walker class, but I am still confused where to put the querystring "id" value so it displays in each one:

```
// Walker Nav Menu
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
     function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
 {
       global $wp_query;
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
       $class_names = $value = '';
       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
       $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
       $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
       $prepend = '<b>';
       $append = '</b>';
       $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';
       if($depth != 0)
       {
                 $description = $append = $prepend = "";
       }
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
 }
}
```

I have a feeling it's in the "attributes" section...  something with those tertiary expressions...  Like "if id not ''" add THIS...  but I'm missing it...

Any help is appreciated.

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no filters available to modify the `href` atteribute. To do this you need to create a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class). And build your own menu. It's not that hard to do.

More information:

- [example](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/#example-code)
- [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/)

Comment: Hello janw, thank you very much for the link!  It's one of those things that someone just needs to tell you that you can't do it the way you want to :)  I will give this a shot and share my results.  Thanks again!

Comment: Its possible to do, give it a shot and when you get stuck let me know. Word of advice, if possible rename the `id` to something more meaning full

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I created a walker, but I'm still confused as to where i put the querystring "id" value to concatenate...  Added the code above.

Comment: For other people viewing this...  If you are using something other than the wordpress stock template, they most likely have a custom walker file...  Mine was located in theme-function.php...