# Carry URL variable across the page

Tags: wordpress, variables, url

Hy to Everyone,
I want to carry my `?ref=***` URL variable through my menus in a WordPress site.
This variable will be added by me manually for the URLs and given for the users.
It would be good that if they navigate, the ref variable didn't get lost in a browser session.
How could this be done?
Thank you, I am looking forward to the answer!
BR

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know Javascript or comfortable in adjusting the theme code?

Comment: I couldn't try anything, because I can't write codes. My knowledge is only enough for modifying a script when it's so-so complete. I wanted to search something on the internet but I don't know what to search, what keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will point in the right direction based on the comments.

[Wordpress - Update ALL menu links in header with querystring value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582817/wordpress-update-all-menu-links-in-header-with-querystring-value)

Another solution which is less complex but also less advised is to use javascript to update all **anchors** on the page with the **query string** and value